# C#: Compare different sets of objects with the same property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem that I'm not sure of the best way to solve.  And my "solutions" are leading to very involved code.

Example:  My data model has Sofas, and Apples.  Both the Sofa class and the Apple class have a IsFavorite property and a FavoriteChange date. I have a service that I use like so:

```
 List<Apple> top25FavApples = _appleService.FindFavorites(25);
 List<Sofa> top25FavSofas = _sofaService.FindFavorites(25);
```

Now that I have my apples and sofas which are favorited, I need to Aggregate the collections, Order by FavoriteChangeDate and then limit to the top 25.  This is where I get stuck.

Possible Solution:  Create an intermediary class to hold the Apple/Sofa and the FavoriteDate.  Perform selections on a collection of the intermediary objects and then run another query to get back the Apples and Sofas on their own.

Comment: You can make Apple and Sofa inherit an `IFavoratable` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be create a `IFavoriteable` interface that defines the `FavoriteChangeDate` property and have the two classes implement it. You can then just cast to `IFavoriteable` and do a Linq `OrderBy` on it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Apple> top25FavApples = _appleService.FindFavorites(25);
        List<Sofa> top25FavSofas = _sofaService.FindFavorites(25);

        List<IFavoriteable> top25Total = top25FavApples.Concat<IFavoriteable>(top25FavSofas)
                                                       .OrderBy(x => x.FavoriteChangeDate)
                                                       .Take(25).ToList();

    }
}

public interface IFavoriteable
{
    DateTime? FavoriteChangeDate { get; }
}

public class Apple : IFavoriteable
{
    public DateTime? FavoriteChangeDate { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class Sofa : IFavoriteable
{
    public DateTime? FavoriteChangeDate { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add some interface or base class (which would be better) one option would be to cast to dynamic and query in dynamic fashion, e.g.:

```
top25FavApples.Cast<dynamic>()
    .Concat(top25Sofas.Cast<dynamic>())
    .OrderBy(x => (DateTime)x.FavoriteChangeDate).Take(25)
```